# How to align half div with css grid?

Tags: html, css

I have four `div`s. How do I align the second and third in one line? (50% each)

I have tried to do the following:

```css
.wrap { display:grid; grid-template-columns:1fr; grid-template-rows:1fr "auto auto" 1fr; }

.wrap > div {border:1px solid; background:#4472C4;}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
 <div></div>
</div>
```

[image]

But chrome doesn't apply this style. maybe I am doing this wrong.
How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a grid of two columns, and set `grid-column: span 2` for the items you want to have full width.

```css
.wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.wrap>div {
  border: 1px solid;
  background: #4472C4;
  min-height: 2em;
  margin:0.3em;
}

.wrap>div:nth-child(3n+1) {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> grid-template-rows:1fr "auto auto" 1fr;
> ```

This is nonsense. `grid-template-rows` provides a template for the size of each column in **every** row.

It doesn't describe each row one by one.

`"auto auto"` is not a valid size.

---

Create a 2x3 grid, then make the first and last elements span multiple cells in it.

```css
div {
  border: solid #aaa 1px
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "Top Top" "Left Right" "Bottom Bottom";
}

.Top {
  grid-area: Top;
}

.Left {
  grid-area: Left;
}

.Right {
  grid-area: Right;
}

.Bottom {
  grid-area: Bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="Top">Top</div>
  <div class="Left">Left</div>
  <div class="Right">Right</div>
  <div class="Bottom">Bottom</div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is solution without set areas with grid?